# Apache Camel Nettty : Unable to receive message in TCP socket via netty component

Tags: java, tcp, apache-camel, netty, tcpserver

I am using Apache camel netty component to create a tcp socket server connection to listen ISO8583 message. While using java based clients to send message, I am able to receive the message.

But when I hit from a remote stratus VOS system, unable to receive the message. But the same message can be received using a standalone java tcp server.

Below is my  netty server code :

```
context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            
             public void configure() throws Exception {
             from("netty:tcp://localhost:9011?textline=true&encoding=ISO-8859-1&sync=true")
             .process(new Processor() {

                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws InterruptedException {
                    String data="";
                    data=exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                    System.out.println("Received Message : "+data);
                    
                }
            })
             .to("log:?level=INFO&showBody=true");
             }
             
         });
         context.start();
         Thread.sleep(30000);
```

Please help on how to receive message on this case? Am I doing anything wrong!

Comment: Are you aware that the start method is non blocking, so your JVM may terminate quickly. Try adding some thread sleep after start and test again.

Comment: @ClausIbsen Sorry, actually this is there in the actual code. I haven't added in the problem code snippet.